# Nginx proxy_pass is much faster than direct download

Tags: performance, nginx

I have a java web-server on the host

```
http://192.168.0.1:80
```

This host is not **local**, it's accessed over VPN from internet. I have the file on the host:

```
http://192.168.0.1:80/100mbFile.zip
```

When I download it with Opera or Firefox directly I get the 32-35 kb/s download speed.

But when I access this file with the Nginx installed locally the speed is faster with x3. The config is like this:

```
# I simplify the config removing unnesessary information from it.
server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  nginx.local;

        location /download {
            rewrite /download /auth_download last;
            # /auth_download return X-Accell-Redirect to /internal_download
        }

        location /internal_download {
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
            proxy_pass http://192.168.0.1:80/100mbFile.zip;
        }
    }
}
```

The file is downloaded with about 140 kb/s. Why? Summary:

```
Opera -> http://192.168.0.1:80/100mbFile.zip - ~35kb/s
Opera -> http://nginx.local:8080/download (Local Nginx proxy_pass) - ~140kb/s
```

How is it possible? Nginx installed locally on 127.0.0.1, internet connection are the same, bandwidth are the same too. All are the same. No cache is used in Nginx conf. My OS is Windows XP

Comment: Dont you mean that proxy_pass is slower ? When you access the file on port 80, your download is served by your java web server. When you use 8080 your download is served directly by nginx. This is why its faster. Your access on port 8080 isnt doing a proxy pass.

Comment: @AshrayBaruah No, proxy_pass is being faster than direct access

Comment: What IP does nginx.local resolve to ?

Comment: nginx.local is 127.0.0.1. I'm working with nginx about 2 years and that situation is fenomenal

Comment: @AshrayBaruah. no no no! proxy_pass is faster, much faster

Comment: Nginx server and java server are located on the different machines. Nginx is installed locally. Java server is on another machine and accessed over vpn from internet (it's far away on the another continent). I'm accessing the nginx server from the same computer where nginx is installed, yes it's local.

Comment: @odiszapc I see. So you're using nginx as a 'download manager' since its proxying the request to the remote server. Alright, are you certain that nginx is routing the connection over the VPN ? If  yes, maybe nginx is downloading the file in 'chunks' thereby accelerating the download ?

Comment: Yes. Nginx is like a transparent proxy to some url. I'm using nginx fot X-Accel-Redirect feature to authorize access to files from my Rails app. Behavior with speed increase I've explained is a good bonus but I don't understand how it's possible. Yes nginx routing over the VPN. I think the answer is inside inner nginx transfer mechanisms

Comment: Well, you could try monitoring the threads on your java web server to see how many requests nginx is making. Maybe it is chunking the download to speed it up.

Comment: Java server doesn't support any chunking. Ok, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx caches content so it does not require disk IO and is served from memory thus much faster.

See this article https://web.archive.org/web/20120622205256/http://mark.ossdl.de/2009/07/nginx-to-create-static-files-from-dynamic-content/

Comment: I don't use caching. The file I download is not static file really. The 100mbFile.zip is dynamically constructed from chunks on the remote java server

Comment: No cache. I download a dynamically generated file within 100Mb size from another server with proxy_pass. You are wrong.